# MS-Access Docmd to Open a Report

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to speed up the report creation in MS-Access?  Currently I am using

```
Dim reportName As String
reportName = "RPT_MonthlyTargetCompliance_IMPLEMENTATION"
fileName = folderPath & "myFile.pdf"


    DoEvents
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, fileName
    
    
    DoEvents
    DoCmd.Close acReport, reportName, acSaveNo
```

Comment: Yes, optimise the query driving the report.

Comment: The report has 3 sub reports - each with their own querys.  Is that the correct way of doing that?

Comment: Yes. Try running each subreport and start optimising the slowest. However, without your data and report, nor queries, it is hard to be specific - really not a question for SO.

Comment: Yes this is the correct way. Sometimes you might be able to replace a sub report by the grouping feature. I.e. You can create multiple nested groups having group headers and footers. This is often faster than sub-reports, because only on single query is required.